# Problem solving this system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have to solve this set and should find for $x$, $x=-z$ and for $y$, $y=z$, but I don't know how did they find those values for $x$ and $y$.

Here is the system :
\begin{cases} { -5x+2y-7z =  0  } \\ { -3x-4y+z =  0  } \end{cases}

Solutions :
$x=−z, y=z, z\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What were your own attempts ?

Comment: usually I know how to solve sets of equations like these but I couldn't do it with this one. Could you please help me out?

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward problem in solving systems of equations.  I would recommend the Elimination method.  Start with eliminating the y variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the two equations equal to each other.

   -5x + 2y - 7z = -3x - 4y + z
2. Combine like terms and get x alone

   2x = 6y - 8z

   x = 3y - 4z
3. Plug in for x in one of the equations and get y alone (I chose -3x - 4y + z = 0)

   -3(3y - 4z) - 4y + z = 0

   -9 y + 12z - 4y + z = 0

   3y = 3z

   y = z
4. Plug in for y in x = 3y - 4z

   x = 3(z) - 4z

   x = -z
5. Done!!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Remark that the two equations are independent so the dimension of the set of the solutions is $3-2=1$.

Now, let's call $(1)$ your first equation and $(2)$ your second equation. Try

- $(1)-\frac{5}{3}(2)$.
- $2(1)+(2)$.

Can you continue from here ?